# the gif cannot be decoded

Tags: android

i met a problem now , the android system can not decode gif files , but we need to do that job , how can i do that , if you know that , pls tell me , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A very rough answer, look up the file format for GIF, then open and read the file, then set the pixels of drawable/bitmap.

You could probably find GIF decoding routines on the net that you can use.

Comment: thanks raybrittion, i got it, i use a opensource giflib and it works well.

Comment: Can you mark this as solved please.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say where you are getting the GIF files from - off the SD card, out of resources or from a URL?

For the URL case, BitmapFactory decoding will read GIF files, but only if you go about it the right way. For example (getting the default Facebook profile pic)

```
mUri = new URI("http://graph.facebook.com/100002092153001/picture?type=large");
mRequest = new HttpGet(mUri);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(mRequest);

HttpEntity  entity      = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

The key here is getting the response content as an inputStream. If you get bytes and then use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes), you get back a null bitmap.

This also works for JPGs. I haven't tested it yet with PNGs.